# Javascript validation of fields in a form

Tags: javascript, validation

I am doing javascript validation for empty checking of a text field in my form.. I want to know which of the following is the best method and why?

Method 1

```
if($("#myField").val()==''){
alert("Cannot be empty");
}
```

Method 2

```
var check=$("#myField").val();
if(check==''){
alert("Cannot be empty");
}
```

Which of them is best?? Method 1 or Method 2..And why??

Comment: Please say whats wrong with the code before downvoting the post??? So it will be helpful for me to understand next time..

Comment: Someone probably downvoted because it's vague question, regarding coding style rather than actual problem to be solved. Both of methods you presented may be used both have their strengths. There's no one great answer to that and this question may lead to mute discussion, therefor it's no good format for SO.

Comment: I heared that assiging a value to a variable caues memory wastage.. so i want to know about better suggestions..

Comment: @User Reducing memory usage on a small scale like this is barely quantifiable in terms of performance, and micro optimizations such as this are generally only performed if the benefit outweighs the implementation cost (time spent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method 1 only, if you dont need the value of that input field again later in your code.

Use method 2 if you are reusing that value later in your code. But I'd advise to use a more meaningful variable name like fieldValue instead of check.

Comment: Yes you are correct.. But i just posted an example here.. any way thanks for the reply